# Hide/Show value text of Input on focus and blur using jQuery

Tags: jquery, textbox

I have value attribute of an input. I need it to disappear on focus for that particular textbox, and reappear on blur, if the textbox has no content.

This is my current HTML code.

```
 <label>First Name</label></td>
 <input class="required" type="text" name="firstname" value="Fill" id="firstname" /><span>(required)</span>
```

Similarly i tried one other thing.When focus is in(Textbox A),a new textbox(B) appears and when focus is out(From A),B gets disappeared.But here is something wrong.I need the user to enter something in Box B also.Now i need something this.When focus is out from A as well B,only then B should disappear.
Note:There are number of text box on the page.
This is Code for it.

```
$('#lastname').focusin(function () {
        $('input.hidden').fadeIn(1000);
        $('input.hidden').css('backgroundColor', 'yellow');
        }).focusout(function () {
        $('input.hidden').hide();
        });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean that the value of the textbox should disappear on focus and show up on blur?

Comment: if you want to disappear the value of textbox on focus then there is a solution in html5 using placeholder

Comment: Yeah.But not that value which is entered by someone.Only text of value attribute("Fill") should appear or disappear.

Answer (score 5):

```
​$("#firstname")​.on({
    focus: function() {
        if (this.value==='Fill') this.value = '';
    },
    blur: function() {
        if (this.value==='') this.value = 'Fill';
    }
})​;​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qrSAp/)

If older browsers are'nt an issue, you don't really need javascript for this:

```
<label>First Name</label>
<td> 
    <input placeholder="Fill" id="firstname" />
    <span>(required)</span>
</td>​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qrSAp/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var fill = $('#firstname').val();

$('#firstname').on('focus', function() {
    $(this).val('');
}).on('blur', function() {
    if ($('#firstname').val() == "") {
        $(this).val(fill);
    }
});​
```

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/jcwvM/3)

Comment: You didnt ask about that in the question, but I have updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(".required").on("blur", function(){
  $(this).attr("value", "Fill");
}).on("focus", function(){
  $(this).attr("value", "");
});
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AkpVd/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" id="sample" value="Fill"/>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

You can then use `Jquery` to handle `focus` and `Blur`event for your `textbox`

```
     $('#sample')​.on("focus",function(){
             $(this).val("");
            }).on("blur",function(){
             $(this).val("Fill");
                                       })​;​​
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/29nrT/1/)**