# alert text field value when someone enters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a text field say

```
<input id="hello" type="text" name="suraj" />
```

When someone enters a value in this field, Is there a way to alert that value (without any button click) in javascript or jquery.

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: you want the alert on focus out of text input or while typing?

Comment: not while typing. typed value should show up

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

Comment: Can you be more specific about the trigger event?  Would you want this to happen after any keystroke, after a change, or after the cursor leaves the field (loses focus)?  It's tricky to determine when a user has finished "typing," but these other events are easily spotted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide/Show value text of Input on focus and blur using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018001/hide-show-value-text-of-input-on-focus-and-blur-using-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On keypress you will get multiple alerts. If you handle on focusout then you can see the typed value. Use this code if you can handle on focusout.

```
$('#hell').on('focusout', function(){
  alert(event.target.value);
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.keyup()` event as shown below :-

```
$('#hell').on('keyup',function(){
   alert($(this).val());
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5L5d6w4v/)

Or(if you want to alert text as soon as user finished typing then use `.blur()` event as shown)

```
$('#hell').on('blur',function(){
  alert($(this).val());   
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5L5d6w4v/1/)

Or you can also use `.focusout()` event as shown

```
$('#hell').on('focusout',function(){
    alert($(this).val()); 
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5L5d6w4v/2/)

Answer (score 1):

here are some following event for keyboard

http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

http://api.jquery.com/keydown/

http://api.jquery.com/keyup/

and try

```
$('#hell').on('keyup',function() {
       alert($(this).val());
    });
```

or

```
$('#hell').on('keydown',function() {
       alert($(this).val());
    });
```

or

```
$('#hell').on('keypress',function() {
   alert($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use ***focusout*** event, this way..

```
$('#hell').on('focusout',function(){
   alert($(this).val());
});
```

Or you can use ***blur***

```
$('#hell').on('blur',function(){
  alert($(this).val())      
});
```

Comment: this is alerting for every alphabet, I want it after the text or value gets completed, i.e. when out of focus

Comment: I did the exact same thing and you guyz are discussing that on my answer. :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use `keyup` event like below

```
$('#hell').on('keyup',function()
{
   alert($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this.

```
 <input id="hell" type="text" name="suraj" onChange="toggle()"/>

    <script language="JavaScript">
        function toggle() {
       var value = document.getElementById('hell').value;
       alert(value);
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: It will not give expected output , i mean it will not alert the text enters in the textbox, If you want that then change var value = document.getElementById('hell'); this line to var value = document.getElementById('hell').value;